# sumif rows and columns from two or more tables using header Index/Match

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How do I sumif rows and columns from two tables? The formula should match each tables row number and column headers, find the intersection and sum it.
I can only do this manually using sumif, but I'd like an actual formula so I don't need to search for the header for Table 2. I'm open to forumla or vba

essentially the formula is so:
`=SUMIF("Table 3 ID Column",Table 1 ID,"Table 2 Income")`

This is not correct but looking for something like this:
`=SUMIF("Table 3 Col", Value, ADDRESS(MATCH(Value,Col array,0) , MATCH(header Value ,header array,0),1))`

Example

```
Table 1
ID  Name
25173   Blue
25710   Debbie
64092   John
64094   Apples
6959    Oranges
6983    Amy


Table 2
ID  Income
25173   142
6983    298
64092   2205
25173   462
25173   346
64092   644


Table 3
Desired Output      
ID  Name    Income
25173   Blue    950
25710   Debbie  0
64092   John    2849
64094   Apples  0
6959    Oranges 0
6983    Amy 0
```

[[update]]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zuaia.png)

Comment: So in Table 3 what do you start with, Only the IDs or both the IDs and Names?

Comment: @ScottCraner ID is most important here

Comment: If the row or column in which it starts is not defined then the best way to proceed is to to make the data into actual tables with proper table structures and do what @Slai stated.  Otherwise the formulas will get unruly and prone to error.

Comment: @ScottCraner that's a lot of memory for 500k rows, okay well thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tables are Excel Tables ( Home > Format as Table ) then you can copy Table**2** and add a new table column with this formula

```
= SUMIF( Table2[ID], [ID], Table2[Income] )
```

[image]

Comment: thats exactly what i have in the question.... but it assumes table header location is same... i want it to SEARCH

Comment: @JamAndJammies with Excel tables the order or location of the column does not matter even if you re-arrange the columns in Table2 as it references the range by the header name.

Comment: Doesn't work, I dont think you understand the question. There's no way to know which col needs to be added if its not searched or specify. I added a picture

Comment: @JamAndJammies I don't think you understand the answer. I added a picture too. If you format the ranges as tables, in Excel 2007 or above you can use [structured references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Comment: I don't know what version of excel you have, but that doesn't show anything.. you are literally putting in `Table2[Income]`? This doesn't even look right... I don't know how you can get there..

Comment: @JamAndJammies you can select the table ranges and in the Home tab select Format as Table (or click Table in the Insert tab)

Comment: okay thanks.. quite a disappointing though... seems memory intensive.....but thanks

Comment: @JamAndJammies I expect this to be a tiny bit more efficient than a Index/Match Excel formula. You can compare by saving the file as `.xls` which will remove the structured references and convert them to absolute addresses like in your example.